# CPU limit on individual runable jar files

Tags: java, cpu

I have a .sh script with many jar files in it. Each jar file has unique launch arguments. I must limit all the jar files to not use more than %5 CPU each.

```
nohup java -a dsasda -p adss
nohup java -a dsasad -p adds
nohup java -a dsdasa -p adsa
nohup java -a dsdsa -p adds
nohup java -a ddassa -p adas
```

I've been reading about the cpulimit tool, how do I use it to target individual jars?

Answer (score 1):

You can start a program using `cpulimit` with the syntax `cpulimit -l limit -- program`, so you'd need to do:

```
cpulimit -l 5 -- java -a dsasda -p adss
cpulimit -l 5 -- java -a dsasad -p adds
...
```

(edit: if you also need `nohup` you do need to run it too, of course: `nohup cpulimit -l 5 -- java -a ...`)

Comment: Sorry that isn't working.

Comment: it seems to work from terminal emulator when launching just a jar file, but when running a .sh and having 3 lines of arguments it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: weird. it started working when i did nohup cpulimit -l 5 -- java -a dsasda -p adss

Comment: @WebMaster: that makes sense, as your other code was also using `nohup`, I hadn't seen it.